# sum about the zeta Function

Tags: calculus

it is possible to show
$$\sum _{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^k \zeta (k)}{k!}=-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(1+i) \sqrt{x} \left(K_1\left((2-2 i) \sqrt{n} \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{x}\right)-i K_1\left((2+2 i) \sqrt{n} \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{x}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{n}}-2 \gamma  x+x+x (-\log (x))-\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum _{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^k \zeta (k)}{k!} = \sum_{k\ge 2} Res(\zeta(-s) \Gamma(s)x^{-s},-k)\\= \sum_{k\ge 2} Res(\frac12(2\pi)^{-s} \zeta(1+s)\sin(-\pi s/2)\Gamma(1+s) \Gamma(s)x^{-s},-k)\\=\mathcal{M}^{-1}[\frac12(2\pi)^{-s} \zeta(1+s)\sin(-\pi s/2)\Gamma(1+s) \Gamma(s)](x) \\ \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad - Res(F(s)\zeta(1+s)x^{-s},0)-Res(F(s)\zeta(1+s)x^{-s},-1)\\ 
 = x^{1/2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1/2}} f(nx) - A - Bx-Cx \log x$$
$$f(x) = \mathcal{M}^{-1}[F(s-1/2)](x), \qquad  F(s) = \frac12(2\pi)^{-s} \sin(-\pi s/2)\Gamma(1+s) \Gamma(s)$$